# Log4j 2 logging output message with link to the file number

Tags: java, log4j

Previously I used log4j version 1 where I had following log4j.xml configuration file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="info" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level Line: %L  - %msg%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.ma.dev" additivity="false">
    <priority value="INFO" />  <!-- <priority value="${myinfo}" /> --> 
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE" />
</category>


<root>
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="UNMAPFILE" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

This config generate following log output where I have link to the logging line:-

[image]

I tried trying to get similar log output for log4j version 2 with following config file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="priorityLevel">info</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="myConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level Line: %L  - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${priorityLevel}">
            <AppenderRef ref="myConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I got the output as:-

[image]

No link. How can I have link in Log4j version 2?

Answer (score 2):

The link pattern in IntelliJ console seems to be "class(file:line)".

You can try to set pattern to:

%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p} %c{1}:%C(%F:%L) - %m%n

Comment: You can also replace `%C(%F:%L)` with just `%l`. In the OP's example replacing `%-5level` with `%-5l{}evel` will give the same result as in Log4j 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

In Log4j1, `%l` meant “location”, so where you have `%level` you get the logger location + evel.

In Log4j2, location has changed to `%c` which outputs the name of the logger (which is the class name, if you’re instantiating your loggers correctly with  `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class)` where    `foo` is your class’ name.

`%level` prints the logging level, so you will need to change this to `%c` in your PatternLayout configuration to get the same output as you are when using Log4j1:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %c %-5level Line: %L  - %msg%n"/>
```

Check out the Layout page from the log4j2 documentation and scroll down to PatternLayout for more https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and also nice explanation. If I check the layout link, I don't find how to get link to the logline. As I asked peculiarly for how to get the link to the logline. If I try  ur suggestion "<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %c %-5level Line: %L  - %msg%n"/>"  The output as follows. But there is no link.    

"09:02:45.320 [main] com.ma.dev.LoadApp INFO  Line: 11  -  main testing"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In your screenshot it seems you are using IntelliJ. I might be wrong, but I think it's possible to get to the log line (or at least the class calling the logger) by holding down CTRL and left-clicking on the class name in the log (i.e. hold down CTRL and click on "com.ma.dev.LoadApp" in the log in 
the console)